# Wiring- changing from a fan light combo to a fan light combo with remote control

Tags: electrical, wiring, ceiling-fan

I am replacing an old fan/light combo that was operated by side by side light switches. I have replaced it with a light/fan combo that also has a remote. I can only get the light switch to operate either the fan or light. 
One side of the remote has a black and white wire which I have connected to the black and white from the ceiling. The other side of the remote has a black blue and white which are connected to the black blue and white from the fan.

There is also a red wire that is coming out of the ceiling, I tried connecting it to he two blues from the remote and Dan and then I tried connecting t to the black wires from the remote and fan. Either way the light switches will operate either the fan or light but not both. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you add some images of your junction boxes?

Comment: Do you want to be able to use the remote still, and if so, do you still want dimming and/or fan speed control functions from it? Are you open to replacing the existing wall switches?